# Is it possible to establish a Bluetooth connection with a Java/Android client and Python server?

Tags: android, python, sockets, bluetooth, client-server

I am trying to make a bluetooth connection with my Android client and a Python server. However, I am unable to do so since my Android client always fails to connect. Now I am wondering whether it is possible at all to use an Android Bluetooth socket and a python socket together. Is that possible?

And if so, do you have suggestions what else I might try? In a nutshell, this is what I do:

**My Android client:**

I get a Bluetooth device like this:

```
BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().
    getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
```

Where `deviceAddress` is equal to the bluetooth MAC address of my laptops bluetooth adapter. Which is `E0:F8:47:3F:80:49`

Then I use that `device` to create a Socket:

```
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
```

Where `MY_UUID` is this string: `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`

After that I just call connect:

```
socket.connect();
```

And that is where it fails to connect. Maybe it is because of server wihich looks like this:

**My Python server:**

```
import bluetooth 

hostMACAddress = 'E0:F8:47:3F:80:49' # The MAC address of a Bluetooth adapter  
port = 3 
backlog = 1
size = 1024
s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
s.bind((hostMACAddress, port))
s.listen(backlog)
try:
client, clientInfo = s.accept()
while 1:
    data = client.recv(size)
    if data:
        print(data)
        client.send(data) # Echo back to client
except: 
    print("Closing socket")
    client.close()
    s.close()
```

Comment: Is your server listening and accepting new connection requests? Client and server have to use the same UUID. Is your server discover-able?

Comment: Well, I got it to work now! I provided the client and server with the same uuid. And I used this server instead of the one above https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/examples/simple/rfcomm-server.py